# Local python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

(I'm new to Python and venv, so please bear with me)

I have a Python application that needs Python 3.6 (or later) and many libraries.

I've already used venv to create a requirements.txt that specifies all the libraries I need.  I've successfully installed and run my app on a new machine with  Python 3.6.

Now, I need to run it on a machine where I do not have root access, and where Python 3.5.5 is installed.  What are the steps to install a local copy of a more recent Python and have it be used in my venv?

Comment: Is your machine windows or Linux. (where you want to try your code (which operating system its have))

Comment: Linux.


_... min text ..._

Comment: It is not required to have root access for running your setup on your remote machine locally. Can you make similar env there with python3.6 installed using `sudo`

Comment: NO, i think he doesn't know the sudo password for that Pc/Machine

Comment: you can create a venv without super user privilage  by using                            
     pip install --user virtualenv

Comment: I have venv running already.  I'm asking a more nuanced question:  How do I tell venv to use a different version of python?  (I'm guessing that I need to somehow install it in a local dir, and then add some line into requirements.txt ??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to create a Python 3.6 venv, the host machine must have Python 3.6 installed.

You can't have a virtual environment of Python 3.6 if the 3.6 is not installed on system. But if you have an already created venv in 3.6, you can very well move it to target machine. Both servers must have same OS.

If your target machine OS is different, then you have to install python 3.6 to your home directory, check [here](https://passingcuriosity.com/2015/installing-python-from-source/) for installantion instructions (basicly you will use `./configure prefix=/home/david/python3.6` while installing).

After installing python 3.6, use `-p` flag for venv to point **your** python executable like this: `venv -p /home/david/python3.6/bin/python`

Comment: Righto.  So, can I install Python 3.6 under my homedir, or must it be installed globally?  And, once I do install a private copy, how do I tell venv to use it?

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb Just copy your venv to target machine, if you have same OS. After activating the venv, python interpreter will be available.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But, my questions are (1) How do I install a personal copy of Python; a different version than what is installed globally?; and (2) Once I have installed this version, how do I tell my venv to use it.

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb 2) You can point which python interpreter to use with: venv -p /home/python3.6/bin/python

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb 1) Download python tarball, install from source. User your home directory to install target: ./configure prefix=/xxx/yyy
https://passingcuriosity.com/2015/installing-python-from-source/

Comment: Thanks!
Please edit your comments into your answer and I'll accept.